# Select all conversations with last sent message

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table

```
create table messages(
    id         bigserial primary key,
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    message    text,
    from_id    bigint,
    to_id      bigint
);
```

I'm select all unique conversations by using the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id))
       id, message, created_at
FROM   messages
ORDER  BY LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id), created_at DESC;
```

But I'd like to change it so I get the last message from each conversation. Not the first. Any idea how I can do that? Possible using a different query?

Comment: [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) shows example very close to yours query and says that in this case you get last row for each pair. Because you sorted rows by created_at desc. And  this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IOs83QBl) confirms that.

Comment: @nbk - yes, it does [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kqPavX2l). You inserted pair (10, 201) which adds new row. Everything looks OK.

Comment: The same pair `(from_id, to_id)` would normally be allowed to have many distinct conversations (with 1-n messages). But your table seems seems to lump all messages between the two together. So you are actually looking for the absolute latest message between each pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `created_at` is defined `NOT NULL` (and you are just not showing it), then your query already does what you ask for.

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

If there are **many** messages per pair, then different query styles will perform (much) better.

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

For only **few**, `DISTINCT ON` is just right.